# dropup menus in CSS?

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to build a dropup menu. Basically, I have a website that has different buttons at the bottom and some of them should have dropup menus so that a few buttons apper above it on mouseover.

Oh, and I'd like to have a solution that works without big libraries and maybe even without javascript (but that's just because it's cleaner, a solution with javascript would also work).

**Edit:** Here's some code:

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbarElement" id="toolbarViewUsers">
    <img src="images/usericon.png" />
    List users
</div>
<div class="toolbarElement" id="toolbarSettings">
    <img src="images/settings.png" />
    Settings
</div>
<div class="toolbarElement" id="toolbarLogout">
    <img src="images/logout.png" />
    Logout
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toolbarElement img {
 display: block;
}

.toolbarElement {
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 3px;
 margin-right: 3px;
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

**Edit 2:** Now I tried this, but I still don't know how to place the submenu above the toolbarElement:

CSS:

```
.toolbarElement {
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 3px;
 margin-right: 3px;
 position: relative;
}

.submenu {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbarElement" id="toolbarSettings">
 <img src="images/settings.png" />
 Settings
 <div class="submenu">
  Hallo
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't care for animations then this is quite easy with a bit of CSS. I don't have time to go into details, so I'm leaving this as a comment, not an answer :-)

Comment: we're not here to do your homework for you; give us some code, and we'll give you some help.

Comment: @cambraca: Well, I thought of putting visible-on-hover divs above the items, but I don't know how to place the div above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think is a good example:

[jQuery multi-tiered drop-up menu](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-multi-tiered-drop-up-menu.html)

Watch demo [here](http://comp345.awardspace.com/superfish/superfish.html).

BTW  just a warning the demo has de drop up way down in the left corner, call me an idiot but i refreshed 5 times before i saw it :)

Good luck

Comment: Ah, ok. Seems like I have to add an empty div that acts as orientation mark.

Comment: No prob.. Happy it helped, Good luck!!