# How to make dropup menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

Wibiya toolbar is good to make an example.

[Look at this](http://jsbin.com/ihimu4) - Click on translate menu.

How to implement the **`Drop Up`** menu? Anybody have done with this? Let me know

Comment: Found it. It's SlideDown() / SlideUp(). Example http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2025-Using-SetTimeout-To-Delay-The-Closing-Of-A-Related-UI-Element-Based-On-User-Interactions.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I answered a similar question, don't know if it helps:

[dropup menus in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329066/dropup-menus-in-css/4329344#4329344)

Good luck!

EDIT: If you want to know the real **basics** I did one for you [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/srHfC/1/) well, the bar at least. (only CSS)

Comment: nice one. let me play with `.mouseover(function()`

Comment: Please tell me if you need anything, I will reply tomorrow. Going to sleep now ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-multi-tiered-drop-up-menu.html